# Python/Flask How to change variable on root route from second route

Tags: python, flask

I rendered my template in root route and I want a post method, in my second route, to redirect to my root route. The issue is I can't change my variable, that I set up in my template, in my second route.

### So I want to change the variable display in my html {{ display }} after I do my POST method.

EDIT:
I figured it out. I needed to change my display to session to carry over after I do a post method and I was getting the form back in unicode so I had to put that in int().

Python:

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, session
    import random
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.secret_key = 'ThisIsSecret'

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        try:
            session['counter'] += 1
        except KeyError:
            session['counter'] = 1
        if session['counter'] == 1:
            session['randnum'] = random.randint(1,100)

        return render_template('index.html')

    @app.route('/play', methods=['POST'])
    def guess():

        if int(request.form['guess']) == session['randnum']:
            session['display'] = 'You Win'
        elif int(request.form['guess']) > session['randnum']:
            session['display'] = 'Too High'
        elif int(request.form['guess']) < session['randnum']:
            session['display'] = 'Too Low'
        else:
            session['display'] = 'Does not recognize that input, try a number.'

        return redirect('/')

    app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>The Great Number Game!</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      #body{
        text-align:center;
        padding-top:200px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body id='body'>
    <h1>The Great Number Game!</h1>
    <p>I am thinking of a number between 1-100</p>
    <p>Take a guess:</p>
    <p>{{ session['display'] }}<p>
    <form class="abc" action="/play" method="POST">
      <p><input type="number" name="guess" value=" "></p>
      <p><input type="submit" name= "submit" value="submit"></p>
    </form>
    {{session['randnum']}}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you want to redirect?

Comment: because I want it to go back to the rendered template defined in the root route

Comment: does the question need to be reworded?

Comment: so why don't you render the template directly instead?

Comment: because it won't use the session variables and arguments from the root route AND it goes to a new page, which wont make it dynamic.

Comment: if i did it going to a new template it wouldnt use all the arguments and would instead keep pulling up a picture of what it looks like without giving it functionality